# Trouble executing example apps in Examples.xcworkspace , XCode tries to execute them all at once

Tags: swift, perfect

Thank you for taking the time to read my question. I am quite new to server side development, but do have some experience with Swift.

I opened Examples.xcworkspace.

So my issue is that I am trying to run Tap Tracker, and

1) when I run it I get this in the output terminal (I think the route of the issue must lie here):
[image]

2) when I go to the URL, it returns the data from the URL Routing example only

3) when I press the button on the iOS app, it returns the following:

[image]

I'm trying to get TapTracker to work on its own, I know that if I open the project on its own and then add PerfectServer and PerfectLib to the project it works, but how do I just run TapTracker if I'm opening it in Examples.xcworkspace?

Comment: How did you run the program? 
Did you run the program using terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you started the program. But I can tell you how I run it successfully.

To execute Tap Tracker only, select Tap Tracker button on the upper left corner of Xcode.

[image]
Select Product -> Run

[image]

Then you'll see Tap Tracker running on your device.

[image]

Tap Tracker needs a corresponding server(Tap Tracker Server) so that it can work.

[image]

You can start Tap Tracker Server using the same way as you start Tap Tracker.